# Creating query to calculate number of employess in each department who are grade 1 or 2

Tags: mysql, oracle11g

I am trying to create a query to calculate the number of employees in each department, their average/min/max/total `SAL` from tables `EMP` and `SALGRADE` for all `EMPNO` who are grade 1 or 2. This is what I have....

```
SELECT AVG(E.SAL),MIN(E.SAL),MAX(E.SAL),SUM(E.SAL),E.DEPTNO,COUNT(*)
FROM EMP E, SALGRADE S 
WHERE S.GRADE=1 OR S.GRADE=2 
GROUP BY E.DEPTNO;
```

I'm not sure if I did this right or not. Specifically with only counting those who are in grade 1 or 2.

Comment: this is right query.

Comment: As @billpennock points out correctly in his Answer, the salary grade for each employee is already present in the EMP table, in which case you don't need to select "from ..., salgrade". Another question for clarification: Do you need to also show all the departments (as they may exist in a DEPT table) that have ZERO employees in salary grades 1 and 2? With avg(sal), min(sal), max(sal) set to null, sum(sal) set to null or zero, and count() set to zero?

Comment: @MrRamzanShah - are you sure about that?

Comment: Linda: are you using Oracle 11g or MySQL? Unless you use both, please edit your post and remove the tag that does not apply. (Once you click the "edit" link under your post, you will find the tags section and you will understand immediately how to remove a tag.)

Comment: What ties EMP and SALGRADE together?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to link two tables, emp and salgrade.  Without the join clause you'll get a cartesian join (all rows of one with all rows of the other) between the two tables before the filter.

```
select avg(e.sal),min(e.sal),max(e.sal),sum(e.sal),e.deptno, count(*) 
from emp e join salgrade s on e.<foreign key value> = s.<primary key value>
where s.grade in (1,2) 
group by deptno;
```

of course is the key value to salgrade is the number then you don't need to join it at all since you're not getting any values in the select from it

```
select avg(e.sal),min(e.sal),max(e.sal),sum(e.sal),e.deptno, count(*) 
from emp e 
where e.grade in (1,2) 
group by deptno;
```

please mark this as the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score -1):

You are querying from two separate tables EMP and SALGRADE, if I see this correctly. You will need to perform some kind of join to bring the tables together. Then on tje resulting join perform your aggregation. with a Group By clause. Assuming that there is a common ID to join them, it could look something like this:

```
SELECT 
AVG(E.SAL),MIN(E.SAL),MAX(E.SAL),SUM(E.SAL),E.DEPTNO,COUNT(*) 
FROM EMP E
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM SALGRADE WHERE GRADE = 1 OR GRADE = 2) S
ON E.ID = S.ID
GROUP BY E.DEPTNO;
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

SELECT AVG(E.SAL),MIN(E.SAL),MAX(E.SAL),SUM(E.SAL),E.DEPTNO,COUNT(*) 
FROM EMP E, SALGRADE S 
WHERE E.SAL BETWEEN S.LOSAL AND S.HISAL AND S.GRADE=1 OR S.GRADE=2 
GROUP BY E.DEPTNO;